# Strange double postback in asp.net because of IIS setting

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, .net-3.5

I have the follow problem. There is an asp.net application running on 5 different servers. On most of them everything is normal. Each page is doing single postback before rendering the result. On only one server we faced very strange problem. The page is rendered with the single post back, but after that, there is another second postback call even the html result is already displayed in the browser. I believe it's because of IIS configuration, but it's my first time facing such thing. Please advice if you have any idea. Always there is a solution to reinstall the fifth server but we won't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the code is the same on all of the servers. Also they are working at same platform (windows server 2008 r2 + IIS 7.5). It could not be because of bad html syntax. The other servers work perfect. The fifth server is still not re-installed, but may be this will be the solution. We've already spent a lot of time searching for the answer, but it looks as strange as it is. I'm not sure if I successfully described it. The additional post back is not a real post back, because the html is rendered, the page is displayed, but the debugger goes one more time through the code. Otherwise nothing else happens. I wonder why the debugger will go again through the code as it won't change anything on the client side. Because on the browser side it seems as the request is finished, the result is received and everything displayed on the page. If you're not debugging it with VS, you won't find any difference - all the 5 servers looks as working equal. If the problem is not a setting in the IIS, it could be a setting in the VS, but which one and why???